# Error at Server Startup while adding ActiveMQ by replacing HornetQ

Tags: spring, rest, activemq-classic

I am using Spring 4, Hibernate, and ActiveMQ using REST APIs

[image]

**ActiveMQ configurations**

```
<bean id="jmsTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsTransactionManager">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"></property>
</bean>

<!-- Configuration for Publishing Jms Messages -->
<bean id="activeMqConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616"/>
    <property name="disableTimeStampsByDefault" value="true"/>
    <property name="useAsyncSend" value="true"/>
    <property name="nonBlockingRedelivery" value="true"/>
    <property name="redeliveryPolicy" ref="redeliveryPolicy"/>
</bean>

<bean id="redeliveryPolicy" class="org.apache.activemq.RedeliveryPolicy">
    <property name="initialRedeliveryDelay" value="60000"/>
    <property name="backOffMultiplier" value="3"/>
    <property name="maximumRedeliveryDelay" value="60000"/>
    <property name="maximumRedeliveries" value="3"/>
    <property name="redeliveryDelay" value="60000"/>
    <property name="useExponentialBackOff" value="true"/>
</bean>

<!--<bean id="outgoingSmsQueue" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
    <property name="physicalName" value="queue/outgoingSmsQueue"/>
</bean>
<bean id="emailServiceQueue" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
    <property name="physicalName" value="queue/emailServiceQueue"/>
</bean>-->

<bean id="activemqOrderQueue" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
    <property name="physicalName" value="ActiveMQ.orderQueue"/>
</bean>
<bean id="activemqDLQ" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
    <property name="physicalName" value="ActiveMQ.DLQ"/>
</bean>

<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="activeMqConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="200"/>
    <property name="cacheProducers" value="true"/>
    <property name="cacheConsumers" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
    <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true"/>
    <property name="deliveryPersistent" value="true"/>
    <property name="explicitQosEnabled" value="true"/>
    <property name="messageIdEnabled" value="false"/>
    <property name="messageTimestampEnabled" value="false"/>
</bean>


<bean id="jmsProducer" class="com.mahopos.jms.JmsProducerImpl">
    <property name="jmsTemplate" ref="jmsTemplate"/>
</bean>


<!-- End Configuration for Publishing Jms Messages -->

<bean id="dlqMessageListener" class="com.mahopos.jms.DlqMessageListener" autowire="byName">
</bean>

<bean id="dlqMessageListenerContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer"
      parent="baseMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="destination" ref="activemqDLQ"/>
    <property name="messageListener" ref="dlqMessageListener"/>
</bean>


<bean id="baseMessageListenerContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer"
      abstract="true">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="jmsTransactionManager"/>
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="10"/>
    <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="10"/>
    <property name="idleConsumerLimit" value="1"/>
    <property name="receiveTimeout" value="5000"/>
    <property name="idleTaskExecutionLimit" value="50"/>
    <property name="cacheLevel">
        <util:constant
                static-field="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.CACHE_CONSUMER"/>
    </property>
</bean>


<bean id="orderQueueListener" class="com.mahopos.jms.OrderQueueListener">
    <property name="demoApiService" ref="demoApiService"/>
    <property name="delay" value="1500"/>
</bean>

<bean id="orderQueueListenerContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer"
      parent="baseMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="5"/>
    <property name="destination" ref="activemqOrderQueue"/>
    <property name="messageListener" ref="orderQueueListener"/>
    <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

Apparently it seems that either ContextLoaderListener is initialized more than one time, but where?

The server runs successfully but the attached image is shown in Chrome (browser) and no REST call is running after server startup.

Comment: What role does HornetQ play here? What's the role of REST?

Answer (score 0):

@justin Bertram, HornetQ was working previously and I replaced it with Activemq, and the application is REST base.
Issue is resolved by adding replacing the dependency from

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.22.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

it seems issue was due to conflicting libraries